# Where Pritunl VPN stores network and OpenVPN settings (interfaces - IPs, DNS, hosts, routes, openvpn server config, etc)?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, openvpn, linux-networking

[Pritunl](https://pritunl.com/) is a FOSS tool for quick setup a selfhosted OpenVPN server. I installed them using official installation manual on my Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS. And now I can't find where Pritunl stores their own config and where placed all main network settings.
I see only one name server `198.18.18.18` in my `/etc/resolv.conf` and `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf`, these files are not symlinked.

I can't find who provides this nameserver. I can't ping this address but my system can resolve hostnames like google.com.

`lsof -i :53` returns systemd-resolve on 127.0.0.53 as it configured at `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf`, and there isn't true DNS server.

`/etc/openvpn` will be empty even when I created two VPN interfaces (tun2 and tun7) via Pritunl WebGUI.

`/etc/hosts` and `/etc/nsswitch.conf` can't help to understand this.

`/etc/systemd/network` is empty. `/etc/network/interfaces.d` contains one config for eth0, but not for tun2 and tun7.

nmcli shows all interfaces (`nmcli device show`) but connection list is empty.

As a result, I can't explain how to add

- a static hostname:ip pair for the machine only or
- for all clients of the VPN server
- some additional config options to OpenVPN server instances
- a dedicated DNS server like dnsmasq (because port 53 is busy and I can't understand where to apply them for all services on the machine).

If Pritunl manages all these settings dynamically via own configurators like nmcli or [ipaddress](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html) how can I affect their default behavior?

Comment: Try nslookup with server command inside then netstat -npl

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you must read docs at first place?
Or search some files with 'pritunl' name?
(/etc/pritunl.conf)

Googled for you:
All data for Pritunl is stored in the MongoDB database.
https://docs.pritunl.com/docs/backup

Comment: I did. But there are no settings for marked DNS nor interface names.

Comment: There is rest api. Documentation says it is outdated and you should use sourcecode for reference.

Comment: @Monerig
 https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/516808/153329

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/358485/153329